# How to completely hide a certain cell from a tableview?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a simple question- I need to hide certain cells from UITableView.
What I found was that delegate method **tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:**
and here is my implementation:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
       return 0;
    return 45;    
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't do the job.The cell is shrunk to a line and I really cannot understand what is going on.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you try updating the data source accordingly?

Comment: That line is probably a separator. Try setting `tableView`'s `separatorStyle` to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`

Comment: @user1065460:check this apple [sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates)

Comment: I actually found a solution.I update the data source numberOfRowsInSection: accordingly  which did a great job definitely.

Comment: Thank you for your answers I will consider them too.

Comment: Think you should read up on the Model View Controller design pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the cell's height to 0 in the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method as well as hiding the cell via the `hidden` property. If you want this effect after a user interaction you will need to reload the table via `reloadData`.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the item from the datasource is the correct way to remove a particular cell entry. (If you try to set, `cell.hidden=YES;` there will be blank space instead of that cell with line separator remaining visible. And you can't remove it by setting cell height to 0)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I actually found a very simple solution updating the data source which works good for me.

Comment: FYI, you CAN use tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath and return 0 from that to get rid of the space if you need to do it this way (i.e. for static tableView's that you can't change the data source for).

Answer (score 0):

That you have to update through the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.